# How to allow python code to continue after a matplotlib graph is executed so that a loop can feed realtime data into the matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hello i'm making an application that allows you to effectively create a youtube poll by counting certain responses and then displaying the results realtime in a graph. My current problem is that my code won't start to loop through youtube chat until i've closed the graph, and if i have the graph appear after the loop then there is no information for the graph to update in real-time as the loop will have stopped. how do i get the graph to appear and then for the loop to go through youtube chat, or is there a more elegant way of achieving the same objective?

```
def animate(i):
    x.append(next(index))
    y1.append(numprompt1)
    y2.append(numprompt2)

    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x, numprompt1, label ='prompt 1')
    plt.plot(x, numprompt2, label ='prompt 2')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')

FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000)

#livechat code
while livechat.is_alive():
  try:
    chatdata = livechat.get()
    for c in chatdata.items:
        print(f"{c.datetime} [{c.author.name}]- {c.message}")
        message = str({c.message})
        
        if prompt1 in message:
            numprompt1 += 1
            print (prompt1, "has been said", numprompt1, "times")
        elif prompt2 in message:
            numprompt2 += 1
            print (prompt2, "has been said", numprompt2, "times")
        
        chatdata.tick()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    livechat.terminate()
    break
```

Comment: The matplotllb examples contain [code](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/animation/strip_chart.html) how to integrate a stream of data into your matplotlib animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

y1 = []
y2 = []
numprompt1 = 0
numprompt2 = 0

fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    
    global y1
    global y2
    global numprompt1
    global numprompt2
    
    a = ax.clear()
    numprompt1 += 1.1
    numprompt2 += 1.2
    y1.append(numprompt1)
    y2.append(numprompt2)
    x = np.arange(len(y1))
    a = ax.plot(x, y1, color = 'green', label = 'prompt 1')
    a = ax.plot(x, y2, color = 'red',   label = 'prompt 2')
    a = ax.legend()
    
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
a = plt.show()
```

Comment: Apart from also using matplotlib FuncAnimation - how exactly is that related to the question?